GeoNetwork : Extract Organisation names defined for all records
With GeoNetwork, I have more 2000 records into the catalog. I need to extract all values currently defined for the Organisation names. With pgAdmin, I have success in querying without error message :
SELECT id, 
       xpath('/contact/CI_Responsability/party/CI_Organisation/name/CharacterString/text()',CAST(data AS XML)) AS organisation_name             
FROM   public.metadata;

However, there the values don't appear into the column :

If needed, I can alo paste the extract of the XLM content :
  <mri:pointOfContact>
    <cit:CI_Responsibility>
      <cit:role>
        <cit:CI_RoleCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/resources/Codelists/cat/codelists.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="originator" />
      </cit:role>
      <cit:party>
        <cit:CI_Organisation>
          <cit:name>
            <gco:CharacterString>Office français de la biodiversité</gco:CharacterString>
          </cit:name>

